# How to use the fontspec package in a LaTeX document?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, texmaker

I'm trying to make a simple document which uses the `fontspec` package in

1. `Tex Maker 4.4.1` with `LuaLaTeX` engine.

Code I'm using

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Arial}
    \begin{document}

    \section*{Introduction}
    This is Introduction

    \end{document}
```

I'm getting this error message (although I've checked LuaLaTeX Engine is set in the drop down menu)

**Tex Maker**

> The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
>
> You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".

Comment: The document is for lualatex and not for luatex. Check in miktex-settings if the lualatex format is enabled. Perhaps you will have to build it. There is type on the document, the command should be `\setmainfont`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled the software and problem got resolved.